# pyqt5) GUI still freezing even though using QThread

Tags: python, pyqt5

What I intended

- when I click 'start' button on Subwindow then loading logo animation starts, and RSC function(Long running function) works separately.

Real work

- when I click the "start" button, the RSC function works but gui freezes.

I'm trying to use QThread for offloading the RSC function... but it looks not working.

Below is my code ↓

1. Main Window(1st window)

   ```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
    from Sub import SubWindow
    from Last import LastWindow
    from functools import partial
    import sys

    class Main_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow) :
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.resize(800, 600)
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            # next pushbutton
            self.pb_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.pb_next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 480, 112, 34))
            self.pb_next.setText('Next')
            self.pb_next.clicked.connect(self.CallSub)
            # quit pushbutton
            self.pb_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.pb_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 480, 112, 34))
            self.pb_quit.setText('Quit')
            self.pb_quit.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        def CallSub(self):
            self.hide()
            self.SW = SubWindow()
            self.SW.show()
            print('call sub')
            self.SW.PB.clicked.connect(self.SW.Loading)
            print('loading')
            self.SW.PB.clicked.connect(self.RSC)
            print('rsc')

        def RSC(self):
            print('start rsc')
            self.text1 = 'host.txt'
            self.text2 = 'access.txt'
            self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
            self.SW.moveToThread(self.thread)
            self.thread.started.connect(partial(self.SW.RunSecurityCheck,self.text1,self.text2))
            self.SW.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
            self.SW.finished.connect(self.SW.deleteLater)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
            self.SW.finished.connect(self.CallLast)
            self.thread.start()

        def CallLast(self):
            self.LW = LastWindow()
            self.SW.hide()
            self.LW.show()
            self.LW.pb_next.clicked.connect(self.CallMain)

        def CallMain(self):
            self.LW.hide()
            self.show()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mw = Main_Window()
        mw.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```
2. Sub Window(2nd window)

   ```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from time import sleep
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

    class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget) :
        finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

        def __init__(self):    
            super().__init__()
            self.resize(800, 600)
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            # Quit PushButton
            self.pb_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.pb_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 480, 112, 34))
            self.pb_quit.setText('Quit')
            self.pb_quit.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
            # start push button
            self.PB = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.PB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 240, 100, 25))
            self.PB.setText('Start')
            # loading animation
            self.LB_loading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.LB_loading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 210, 200, 100))
            self.loading = QtGui.QMovie("loading.gif")
            self.LB_loading.setMovie(self.loading)
            self.LB_loading.hide()

        def Loading(self):
            self.PB.hide()
            self.LB_loading.show()
            self.loading.start()

        def RunSecurityCheck(self,t1,t2):
            sleep(10)
            self.finished.emit()
   ```
3. Last window(3rd window)

   ```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

    class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget) :
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.resize(800, 600)
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            # Next PushButton
            self.pb_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.pb_next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 480, 112, 34))
            self.pb_next.setText('Back to Main')
            # Quit PushButton
            self.pb_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.pb_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 480, 112, 34))
            self.pb_quit.setText('Quit')
            self.pb_quit.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
            # complete label
            self.LB1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.LB1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 220, 221, 18))
            self.LB1.setText('Complete.')
   ```

and below is my loading.gif file

[image]

how could I fix the gui freezing?

Comment: Because widgets (and UI elements in general) are not thread-safe and ***cannot*** be moved (nor created or accessed) to/from external threads. In fact, if you run your code from a terminal or prompt you'll probably see an alert saying "Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread", so, whatever you try to run in that QThread, will actually be run in the *main* thread. Any processing on external threads **MUST** be not directly related to the UI and only use signals to communicate with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in musicamante's comment routines run in a separate thread need to be independent of the GUI.  So what probably makes the most sense in your situation would be to subclass `QThread` and make `RunSecurityCheck` a method of the `QThread`, and pass in your two text parameters to the constructor of the thread.  Then the code that is responsible for freezing the GUI will be run separately and will no longer cause freezing/stalling.

For Example:

in your 1st window file you can make some minor changes to `RSC` method and import the Thread subclass

```
from Sub import SubWindow, Thread

...

    def RSC(self):
        print('start rsc')
        self.text1 = 'host.txt'
        self.text2 = 'access.txt'
        self.thread = Thread(self.text1, self.text2)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.SW.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.CallLast)
        self.thread.start()

...
```

Then in your Sub.py

```
class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget) :
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Quit PushButton
        self.pb_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pb_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 480, 112, 34))
        self.pb_quit.setText('Quit')
        self.pb_quit.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        # start push button
        self.PB = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.PB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 240, 100, 25))
        self.PB.setText('Start')
        # loading animation
        self.LB_loading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LB_loading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 210, 200, 100))
        self.loading = QtGui.QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.LB_loading.setMovie(self.loading)
        self.LB_loading.hide()

    def Loading(self):
        self.PB.hide()
        self.LB_loading.show()
        self.loading.start()


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, t1, t2):
        super().__init__()
        self.t1 = t1
        self.t2 = t2

    def RunSecurityCheck(self,t1,t2):
        sleep(10)

    def run(self):
        self.RunSecurityCheck(self.t1, self.t2)
        self.finished.emit()
```

Your last file doesn't require any changes.

All you need to do is make those few minor changes and Bob's your uncle.  It should work fine.

Comment: omg that's what I missed... you're my Bob. now It perfectly works as I intended. Thank you so much!